# how to declare hooks inside object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using hooks like this

```
const Ref1 = useRef();
const Ref2 = useRef();
const AllRefs = { Ref1, Ref2 };
```

is there anyway to write this in shorthand maybe something like this:

```
const AllRefs = { Ref1:useRef(), Ref2:useRef()};
```

Comment: According to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html you should always use Hooks at the top level of your React function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should it be like this?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const arr = [1, 2, 3];

  const refs = useRef([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={index}
            ref={(element) => {
              refs.current[index] = element;
            }}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```